# How to record cocos2d game play?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, video-capture, video-recording

In my cocos2d game, i need to record game play as a video including sound produced by the game.

How can I implement this? Anybody can help me. Please suggest a way to implement this.

Comment: Are you making a game or application in which you can record yourself playing? Or do you simply want to record a game on your device? If it is the second one, then it is unrelated to programming and probably should not have been asked here.

Comment: @allthewayapps i want capture game play as like talking tom app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i find out kamcord(http://kamcord.com/) SDK for recording game play

Kamcord is a built-in gameplay video and audio recording technology for iOS. This repository contains a Kamcord SDK that works with cocos2d-1.0.1 and allows you, the game developer, to capture gameplay videos with a very simple API. Your users can then replay and share these gameplay videos via YouTube, Facebook, Twitter, and email.

get code here https://github.com/kamcord/cocos2d-kamcord-ios/wiki

Comment: but it's not providing for saving video ... is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a iPad to HDMI converter. From there you can capture video and sound.

Or you can get sound by using the jack on the device and record video with a well placed camera :)